# How to simulate an Open Drain Output (for I2C) in LTSpice?

Tags: i2c, ltspice

I am trying to simulate an I2C line in LTSpice. The part I have trouble is, how can I generate an Open Drain Output?

[image]

How to make V1 as an Open Drain Output? Here are the configuration Options for V1 that I see.

[image]

Comment: You drive a FET with an open drain?

Comment: It is easier to use a FET with its drain open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have one very serious problem shown in your images. You have specified the pulse period to be \$10\:\mu \textrm{s}\$, but the on-time to be \$500\:\mu \textrm{s}\$. That's not going to fly, no matter how you do the rest.

But then you have another serious problem. I assume you want to see an RC time constant taking place. But you've wired up your \$3.3\:\textrm{V}\$ source directly across \$C_1\$. So, once again this isn't going to fly.

It is only a minor problem that you probably don't have much information on your open-drain NMOS output's characteristics. Effectively, you can do reasonable work just knowing the approximate equivalent \$R_{on}\$.

So, I'm going to read between all the lines and take a clue from your circuit about how you want to simulate the switching process. LTspice just happens to have a "SW" part you can probably use. It supports three modes: ON/OFF mode, ON/OFF with hysteresis mode, and a gradual ON, gradual OFF mode. Use the help and type in SW and select that and read the documentation on it. You should be able to achieve what you want in approximating an open-drain output with the SW part (which can be selected easily using F2 to get the dialog box with parts in it.) Since you were looking at an RC time constant of about \$100\:\mu \textrm{s}\$

Here's what an example circuit might look like:

[image]

I've adjusted the period to exaggerate the curves a bit. There are about 5 tau's of time allowed for \$R_1\$ to charge \$C_1\$ back up, so it gets almost back to the top there. Also, note that I set \$R_{on}\$ on the switch to \$100\:\Omega\$. You can set it where you want. But this is one approach.

(By playing with the \$V_h\$ parameter of the switch model, making it negative, you can even get a rise-time out of the switch. I've set it to 0, which just means ON/OFF behavior.)

EDIT: Here's the complete deal from my example:

[image]

Comment: I'm a noob to LTSpice. Your answer is exactly what I am looking for I believe. I am trying to replicate the circuit. How did you select the `.model MYSW SW(Ron=100 Roff=100Meg Vt=2 Vh=0 Lser=10n Vser=0.01` for the Switch? When I right click on the Switch, I don't see a place to add this model.

Comment: @user1406716 Just hit the letter S as a keystroke. It will pop up a SPICE model dialog box for you. You enter the text in, directly. And then just paste it into the schematic anywhere you want. You need to learn about that stuff, too, I suppose. It's easy, once you get used to the idea.

Comment: Did that, I still see this when i see hit the simulation run button. http://imgur.com/a/vr99T

Comment: This is how I entered the `.model ... ` text: http://imgur.com/a/UZpmm

Comment: @user1406716  oh!!!!! Okay. Sorry. I think you have the things swapped around. Yes. Okay. Take a breath. Drop down a new switch (so to avoid any existing complications.) Right click on it and change the Value field to say the name of your MODEL.

Comment: @user1406716 You can ALSO edit the name directly on the schematic. But I'd assumed you knew which one to edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user1406716 Make the instance name anything you like, though. It doesn't care, so far as I'm aware.

Comment: When I try to simulate I still get this: http://imgur.com/a/6v6XL

Comment: @user1406716 NO! You don't put the .MODEL into the VALUE field!!!! Hmm. Ok. Follow my earlier instructions about using the S key. Do that to set up the .MODEL. In your .MODEL, there will be a name. You get to make up that name. In my case, I made up MYSW. You can use ANY other name you want. That's all I did. Then you place that into the schematic. You can see where it is on mine. Then use the name MYSW (or whatever name you make up) in the VALUE field of the SW.

Comment: @user1406716 Does that make sense? The .MODEL is a Spice command. You enter spice commands using the S key. You place them into the schematic, like text. Anywhere. Doesn't matter. Then you use the NAME you made up in the .MODEL, placed into the VALUE field. The switch then FINDS the .model and matches up the name.

Comment: I think I got it (no errors anymore) but I dont see any waveform even after placing the probe at the non-ground terminal of the Capacitor: http://imgur.com/a/odY1W

Comment: This is what I see when I simulate: http://imgur.com/a/mGuMT

Comment: @user1406716 I just added my image to my answer, at the bottom. Select your schematic (click once on it to be sure) and then select View/Spice Netlist and take a look at your list. Name your nodes like I did in mine, to help out, first. Then compare your netlist with my netlist.

Comment: @user1406716 It might be that my resistor value is different, etc. Just check it all over again.

Comment: I got it. My SW was backwards. Thank you so much for holding my hand through this one. I will watch more tutorials of LTSpice before doing more.

Comment: @user1406716 Wonderful! Glad to hear things are now working!

Answer (score 1):

Drive the gate of a MOSFET with your voltage source.